# Errors in reloading Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having lots of problems reloading minecraft. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Java on my computer and tried to re-download a previously purchased Minecraft but it keeps bringing up the following error:

```
Bootstrap (v5) Current time is Mar 15, 2014 11:02:55 AM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_51'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '32'

Looking for update Downloading:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Got reply in: 935ms No update found. Reversing LZMA on
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.pack.lzma to
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.pack Unpacking
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.pack to
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.jar FATAL ERROR:
net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to un-pack200:
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.jar (Access is denied)
at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.unpack(Bootstrap.java:159)     at
net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:123)   at
net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)


Please fix the error and restart.
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling your firewall, or adding an exception for Java/Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

This error message shows, what the problem is:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\launcher.jar FATAL ERROR:
net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to un-pack200: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\launcher.jar (Access is denied) at
[...]
```

The access to `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\launcher.jar` is denied. Are you perhaps editing / using the file while starting the launcher? You might want to try removing (or renaming) your `.minecraft` folder; and see what happens.

Comment: No renaming your .minecraft folder is not a good idea. as if I was using a mod installer it wouldn't work. and it make brake some updates.

Comment: @09stephenb Minecraft mod installers or similar programs will still work fine. I don't want him to change the path in the Minecraft config, I want him to backup his old `.minecraft` folder.

Comment: as .minecraft is a invalid name for explorer he may have problems renaming it back.

Comment: @09stephenb `.minecraft` is not an invalid folder name: The period signals that the folder should be hidden (at least on Unix).

Comment: Make a folder on your desktop called .minecraft and see if you get an error.

Comment: I can create a folder named `.minecraft`. If it doesn't work for you / user71781 you can try this console command: `mkdir .minecraft`

Comment: What OS are you using

Comment: Ubuntu. I have tried this on my Win laptop, and you are right, it doesn't take it. Windows doesn't allow this, but [Win]+[R] "cmd" -> `cd PATH`; `mkdir .minecraft` works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13709/discussion-between-frithjof-and-09stephenb)

Answer (score 0):

Access is denied, huh? You would probably have to run as an administrator to allow access to the file. If it works, you can probably run as normal again. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -4):

Try the method that worked for me, on some computers .minecraft becomes a hidden file. Follow the steps in this link first http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-7/, then go to %appdata% in your file explorer and delete .minecraft.

Comment: **DON'T** delete .minecraft! That is where all of the game data is stored!